# delete all the child rows in sql table by parentid

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms, cascading-deletes

I have a table from which I create a tree with multiple levels and parents. The table structure looks like this.

[image]

When I delete the "TitleID", I want all the children and even the grandchildren to be deleted.
What is the easiest way to do such in sql.
If I simple delete with "where ParentID=TitleID", only children with level 1 depth are deleted.

Comment: This is highly database specific. SQL is just a language that is used by multiple RDBMS'. Which are you using? MySQL? Oracle? SQL Server? ...? You should always tag questions with the relevant RDBMS otherwise most answers will be irrelevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DECLARE @TitleId INT 

SELECT @@TitleId = 2 

;WITH results AS( 
        SELECT  TitleId
        FROM    myTable 
        WHERE   TitleId = @TitleId 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT  t.TitleId 
        FROM    myTable t 
                INNER JOIN ret r ON t.ParentID = r.TitleId
) 

DELETE FROM myTable WHERE TitleId IN (SELECT TitleId FROM    results )
```

Answer (score 1):

To handle tree structured data in relational database, you can add another column `FullID`, which contains value like `1.1.3`. Then what you need is just a simple where clause `WHERE FullID LIKE '1.1.%'` if you want to delete node `1.1` and it's children.

The value of `FullID` can be generated by a stored procedure (for old data), or better by your application (for new data).